# Grep command - file names and numbers of repetitions of a certain word in each file printed in two columns

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep, command

I have a folder with files and what I’m trying to do is to write a shell script which prints the names of the files and the numbers of times a certain word is repeated in those files.

My output should look something like this:

```
filename 3
filename 12
filename 24
…
```

filename includes only the name of the file without the path and the extension.

I managed to do it using a for loop but I think the execution time is not very efficient so my other idea was to use grep command:

```
grep -c “word" */*.txt
```

The output I get looks like this:

```
folder/filename.txt:3
```

I tried to use cut command but I can’t figure out how to avoid cutting the numbers of times the word appears in the different files and there has to be a space between the file names and the numbers.

```
grep -c “word" */*.txt | cut -d'/' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1
```

Any idea how to do this with grep or some other alternative way?

Comment: Please post your non-working code and its output.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jCJL.png

Comment: Output: folder/filename.txt:3

Comment: These are just examples but I think it's clear because my code is really simple.

Comment: Please include your full code (including the loop you are describing).  Put the code in your question (use the formatting tools), not in images or links.

Comment: This is actually a part of a coursework that I have to do and I don't think it is appropriate to post solutions here. I hope it is clear from the information I gave about the problem I have.

Comment: This is homework, and I will not solve it for you.  Start from the fact you are trying to change a colon `:` into a space, and look for a utility that can do that.  There are many, but one very simple exists that will do what you need in a very straightforward, easy to understand way.

Comment: Don't solve it for me but give me some more hints please, what is the command you are taking about?

Comment: Please try your favorite search engine and type in a phrase that says what you want to do, you should find it within a couple of tries at most.

Comment: That was very helpful of you, thank you! :D

Comment: Sed? I also need to remove .txt and when I tried to do it by using cut the colons and the numbers were also removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a nice effort using `cut`. When you can solve a problem with `cut` than most of the time you have found a solid a quick solution.
In this case you need to fix the `cut`command what would give an ugly result.

```
# Ugly cutting
grep -c "word" */*.txt | cut -d'/' -f2 | tr ':' '.' | cut -d"." -f1,3 | tr '.' ' '
```

Fixing `cut`is wrong here, but you can learn cool things

```
# going weird
# Combine first colums
grep -c "word" */*.txt | cut -d'/' -f2 | cut -d"." -f1
# with second column
grep -c "word" */*.txt | cut -d'/' -f2 | cut -d":" -f2
# using paste and process substitution
paste -d" " <(grep -c "word" */*.txt | cut -d'/' -f2 | cut -d"." -f1) <(grep -c "word" */*.txt | cut -d'/' -f2 | cut -d":" -f2)
```

No, this is not the way to solve this. Use `sed` with

```
grep -c "word" */*.txt | sed 's#.*/##;s#\..*:# #'
# or shorter
grep -c "word" */*.txt | sed 's#.*/\([^.]*\).*:#\1 #'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I definitely learned a lot about cut from your answer but I'll use sed like you suggested. :)

Comment: @user408340 If this answer solves your problem, consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark to let others know the problem has been resolved.